# System.NullReferenceException: Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have written a class that deals with opening, writing to, and closing an Excel file.

The methods in the Excel class are being called by a different call. When I call the `addDatatoExcel` method the first time, everything is working, however when I call it again, I get a "System.NullReferenceException: Excel C#". VB says I am passing a null object. I know what the error is I just can not figure out how to prevent it.

```
public class ExcelFile
{
    public static ExcelFile C1;
    private string excelFilePath = "‪‪C:\\Final.xlsx";
    private int rowNumber = 1; // define first row number to enter data in Excel

    Excel.Application excelApp;
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;
    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet;
    int ExcelCounter = 0;
    int checker = 0;
    string str4 = "h";
    
    public   void openExcel()
    {
        excelApp = null;

        excelApp = new Excel.Application(); // create Excel App
        excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        
        excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add();
    }

    public void addDataToExcel(string str4)
    {
        excelWorksheet.Cells[5, 1] = str4;
                      
        ExcelCounter++;
    }

    public void closeExcel()
    {
        excelWorkbook.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add data to the first same Excel sheet that was created.

This is the method that calls the functions in the Excel class.

```
public void AddTextToLabel(string str)
{
        ExcelFile _Excel = new ExcelFile();
        
        if (flag == 1) // Celsius 
        {
            //list Adding Function 1;                
            temp = Double.Parse(str);
            
            x++;
            list.Add(x, temp);
            zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
            CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
            //Example();
            
            if (Excelcounter == 0)
            {
                _Excel.openExcel();
                Excelcounter++;
            }
            
            _Excel.addDataToExcel(str);

            if (Excelcounter == 15)
            {
                _Excel.closeExcel();
            }
        }
}
```

I have checked and the variable `str` that is being passed to `addDatatoExcel` is not null. There are other parameters that change to null when the function is called the second time. Is this because I am not saving the Excel file between every call to `AddDatatoExecl();`

1st call to function

[image]

2nd call to function

[image]

I am new to C# so please be specific. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the Excel, only the first time:

```
// Each time, you call this:
ExcelFile _Excel = new ExcelFile();
...
//The first time, this is called
if (Excelcounter == 0)
{
       _Excel.openExcel();
       Excelcounter++;
}
```

Then the next time you call the `AddTextToLabel` function

```
// A new instance is created
ExcelFile _Excel = new ExcelFile();

// The excel counter is not 0 so the  _Excel.openExcel() will not be called.
if (Excelcounter == 0)
```

Change your code to this:

```
  // Now your excel file is an instance member
  // as is your Excelcounter 
  ExcelFile _Excel = new ExcelFile();
  public void AddTextToLabel(string str)
        {
       
            if (flag == 1) // Celcuis 
            {
                //list Adding Function 1;                
                temp = Double.Parse(str);
                
                x++;
                list.Add(x, temp);
                zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
                CreateChart(zedGraphControl1);
                //Example();
                
                
                if (Excelcounter == 0)
                {
                    _Excel.openExcel();
                    Excelcounter++;
                }
                
                _Excel.addDataToExcel(str);

                if (Excelcounter == 15)
                {
                    _Excel.closeExcel();
                }


            }
```

Comment: My OpenExcel Opens a whole new Excel Sheet. If i was to add that code to where you said. It would just open multiple sheets and only add one value in each sheet.

Comment: The solution I'm proposing, opens only once.